# Overriding Angular $http post to extend every post data with additional data

Tags: angularjs, http-post

In Yii framework, we have to add a CSRF token to the POST data so that the request can be validated.

The token is generated by PHP and I'm passing the variable like this

```
angular.module('MyConstant', []).constant("MyConstant", 
     {'postdata': {'_csrf': 'ABCDEF'}}); //this is written by PHP

var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['MyConstant']);

app.controller('MyCtrl', [
    '$scope', '$http', 'MyConstant',
    function ($scope, $http, MyConstant) {
}]);
```

whenever I want to send POST, I have to do something like this.

```
  $http.post(url, angular.extend(MyConstant.postdata, {data: mydata}));
```

The POST body will be something like this

```
 {"_csrf": "ABCDEF", "data": "bla bla bla"}
```

I'm just curious if there is a "Angular way" to override the `$http.post` to automatically append the data to avoid code duplication like `angular.extend(ViewConstants.postdata` above.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @GregL for the pointers. I can do it like this using `interceptors`

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', 'MyConstant', 
    function ($httpProvider, MyConstant) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function () {
        return {
            request: function (config) {
                if (config.method == "POST"){
                    config.data = angular.extend(MyConstant.postdata, config.data);
                }
                return config;
            }
        };
    });
}]);
```

Comment: If you want to avoid modifying `MyConstant.postdata`, you should use an empty object for the first parameter to `angular.extend()`: `config.data = angular.extend({}, MyConstant.postdata, config.data);`. This is mentioned in the [docs for `.extend()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to register an [interceptor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors).

Just add an interceptor for the `request` method, and check if the `config.method === 'POST'` and if so, add your constant to the data sent (`config.data`).

Comment: It works. I just added the full working code using the `interceptor` you suggested. Many thanks!